# How to get a third person instagram data using Instagram Graph Api

Tags: instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I am successful of fetching my own data using Instagram Graph Api but unable to find a way to get other person's data.
Official document clearly state that metadata of basic data for other Instagram businesses and creators are obtainable but not been able to find any code or document about it.
If anybody know how to do it I would love to know.
Even providing me a link to document or web page that have said information is hugely appriciated.

official document
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api

Answer (score 3):

This is described in the [Business Discovery documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/guides/business-discovery). See also the [API reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-user/business_discovery).

The tricky part is that you need to provide *your Instagram account ID* (or “business account ID”) in the URL. (Basically, your account's node is used to access the `business_discovery` edge.)

You provide the target account's username in the field parameter, for example:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/YOUR_ACCOUNT_ID?fields=business_discovery.username(bluebottle){followers_count,media_count}&access_token={access-token}
```

Where `bluebottle` is the username of the account you want data for.

Mind that this really works with business and creators accounts, so you won't obtain data for any random account this way.

---

Edit: I've covered the process of getting the “business account ID” in [this blog post](https://superface.ai/blog/instagram-account-id). In summary, you can get the account ID of all accessible Instagram profiles using this request:

```
me/accounts?fields=instagram_business_account{id,name,username}
```

([Try it in Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%2Faccounts%3Ffields%3Dinstagram_business_account%7Bid%2Cname%2Cusername%2Cprofile_picture_url%7D&version=v16.0))

You will then use the `id` field of the returned `instagram_business_account` response.

Comment: thank you so much for your reply. I have tried MY_ACCOUNT_ID?fields=business_discovery.username(bluebottle){followers_count,media_count}&access_token={access-token} on Graph Api explorer but i got following error "error": {
    "message": "(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (business_discovery) on node type (User)",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 100,
    "fbtrace_id": "ANRONCBdI5pgKhYPWHou-tB"
  }

Comment: i have following permission pages_show_list
ads_management
business_management
instagram_basic
instagram_manage_comments
instagram_manage_insights
instagram_content_publish
instagram_manage_messages
pages_read_user_content
pages_manage_engagement

Comment: @AkiraYoshimura Yeah, the docs are inconsistent about what "your account ID" is, in this situation you need to use the Instagram account ID (also called Business account ID); I've edited the post with more details on obtaining that.